# Quais as diferenças entre as unidades de tamanhos de fonte "vw", "em" e "%"?

Tags: css

Estou com dúvidas na hora de usar as unidades de tamanho `vw`, `em`, `%`. Pesquisando pela internet sempre vi que uns usavam umas ou outras unidades de tamanho, mas nunca entendi bem a diferença entre elas. Por exemplo, eu não saberia explicar em que situação seria melhor eu usar uma ou outra.

Na criação de um site/sistema responsivo, qual delas é a melhor opção para tal oportunidade?

O que quero entender são as diferenças que existem entre elas e se possível o melhor uso de cada uma em determinada situação

Comment: Segue http://www.sitepoint.com/new-css3-relative-font-size/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As unidades citadas possuem utilização bem parecidas, porém com utilidades bastante distintas, falarei algumas coisas que o Iron Man já disse, contudo, darei um detalhamento mais pormenorizado:

### vw, vh, vmin, vmax

Além do `vm`, existem essas outras unidades, o mais importante que deve saber sobre elas é [**sua compatibilidade**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), que não é a das melhores, porém já estão ganhando um espaço considerável.

O `vw`, como já foi dito pelo nosso amigo Iron Man, estabelece uma relação de porcentagem com a *Viewport Width*, já o `vh` bem intuitivamente refere-se a *Viewport Height*. Além de serem usadas para elementos "quadriláteros" (imgs, divs, etc), podem também ser aplicadas também em textos, para o `font-size`. Com isso você consegue que a fonte se adeque dinamicamente ao tamanho do janela. Olhe [esse JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gz5b3uxw/1/) com um exemplo.

Já o `vmin` e `vmax` estão relacionados com o valor mínimo ou máximo das larguras e alturas, dependendo de qual é o menor e o maior. Por exemplo, se o navegador possui uma largura de 1000px e uma altura de 800px, 1vmin seria 8px e 1vmax seria 10px. Mas se ele foi redimensionado para 800px de largura e altura de 1000px, apesar de terem se invertido largura e altura, o `vmin` e `vmax` continuam os mesmos.

### em, rem

A unidade `em` como já é sabido por muitos é utilizada, em sua grande maioria, para textos.

Uma situação para o `em`: você deu ao `html` e ao `body`  um `font-size: 20px` (este de padrão possui 16px), então todos elementos filhos, consequentemente, terão `20px`. Contudo, você também atribuiu a um `<p>` um `font-size: 1.4em`. O que isso quer dizer? Quer dizer que esse `p` possui um tamanho de fonte igual a 1.4 vezes o fontSize que herdou de seu elemento pai que, **no caso**, foi o body, ou seja, `1.4 * 20px = 28px`.

Situação para o `rem`: se imagine dentro da situação anterior... O parágrafo que possuía um `font-size: 1.4em` (28px), agora foi inserido numa `div` com um `font-size: 30px`. O cálculo atual deverá ser `1.4 * 30 = 48` (30px do elemento pai). Mas se eu quiser que ele herde do elemento-raiz? Como este no caso é o `html`(podendo também se o `body`) (com `font-size: 20px`), basta eu dar ao parágrafo um `font-size` de, ao invés de `1.4em`, o `1.4rem` com o `rem`. O cálculo voltará a herdar do `body` (elemento-raiz).

### Porcentagem %

Não há muito o que falar da porcentagem, esta leva em consideração o elemento pai, e vai também variar de acordo com algumas propriedade `css`, como o `position`.

Assim como o `vw` a porcentagem também pode ser aplicada em textos. Por exemplo, caso o elemento pai de um `<p>` tenha um `font-size: 40px`, e esse`p` tenha um `font-size: 200%`, o tamanho da fonte deste terá o dobro do tamanho da fonte do elemento pai, no caso, 80px.

Resumindo, não terá melhor quando o assunto é responsividade, depende de sua aplicação, do design e da navegação desta. Leia mais sobre este tema e escolha levando em consideração o que achar melhor. Analise os exemplos supracitados e associe-os às suas vivências, assim poderá julgar.

E na minha opinião, os bons *breakpoints* dos *Medias Queries* ainda dão pro gasto quando falamos de fonte e responsividade.

Espero que tenha ajudado...

Answer (score 6):

A unidade `vw` utiliza a largura do viewport ou navegador como base de medida, sendo 1vw equivalente a 1/100 da largura do navegador. Por exemplo se a largura do navegador é 900px, 1vw é igual a 9px.Ela é utilizada tanto para medidas de layout como de fontes. Já a unidade `%` é utilizada mais para definir o layout dos elementos da página, para que eles reajam de acordo com o tamanho do viewport. E o `em` é utilizado normalmente para as fontes, mas também pode ser utilizada para definir alguns detalhes do layout como a margin dos elementos. Por exemplo, caso queira que o elemento tenha uma margin de 2x o tamanho da fonte relativa, você pode usar `margin:2em;`.