# Leading vs line-height

Tags: css, layout

Estou com o seguinte problema na conversão de um layout, eu tenho uma lista de nomes que possui a seguinte propriedade (na imagem abaixo):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Encontrei algumas fórmulas como essa 
Line-height = Font-size + Leading/2, porém na hora de determinar o line-height no css, a distância não fica como está no layout desenhado no meu caso, no Illustrator.

Segue uma imagem que achei útil no entendimento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra dúvida seria onde aplicar o line-height, no caso de uma lista de nomes, eu aplicaria no ul, no li ou no a?

Diferenças:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já testou o espaçamento com paddings ou margins? Geralmente se aplica o line-height no elemento que contenha texto, no caso o link.

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes, setei tudo 0 mesmo, é que o cliente exige o "pixel perfect", então to tentando acertar o line-height

Comment: Você já deu uma olhada na parte de importação de css do Illustrator? Talvez você nem precise quebrar a cabeça para encontrar o line-height...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em sua última dúvida creio as diferenças na aplicação do `line-height` vão depender muito do restante de seu layout. Veja esse exemplo:

```css
ul#lista1{
  line-height: 40px;
}
ul#lista2 li{
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="lista1">
  <li><a>Nomes</a></li>
  <li><a>Nomes</a></li>
  <li><a>Nomes</a></li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul id="lista2">
  <li><a>Nomes</a></li>
  <li><a>Nomes</a></li>
  <li><a>Nomes</a></li>
</ul>
```

Você pode perceber que não há diferenças em relação a sua aplicação. E isso repete inclusive quando há quebra de linha.

Já, quando ao`<a>`crio que não seja necessário aplicação nele, caso ele esteja no modela acima, dentro do `li`. Caso esteja fora, já poderíamos considerar essa atribuição.

Quando quero centralizar um texto verticalmente, (quando usado o line-height), atribuo a este um valor igual a altura do elemento pai.

Outra fórmula que achei é, quando não temos noção do tamanho do elemento, usamos isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso mesmo! Multiplica-se o `font-size` pelo número de ouro, o *phi*.

Em alguns teste funcionou perfeitamente:

```css
ul,li{
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul#lista1{
  line-height: 40px;
}
ul#lista2 li{
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 32.36px;
  background: gold
}
```

```html
<ul id="lista1">
  <li>Nomes </li>
  <li>Nomes</li>
  <li>Nomes</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul id="lista2">
  <li>Nomes</li>
  <li>Nomes</li>
  <li>Nomes</li>
  <li>Nomes</li>
</ul>
```

No caso da segunda lista, o `li` recebeu um `line-height: 32.36px` (20 * 1.618, aproximadamente). E ficou perfeitamente centralizado. Mas este é um caso muito específico, usado para uma boa leiturabilidade, acrescentei porque achei bem interessante.

Pode-se também utilizar margens e `paddings`, mas como optou por um reset...

Comumente, o CSS usa o que é conhecido como `half-leading` para setar linhas de texto. Isto é determinado, trabalhando-se a diferença entre o `line-height` e o `font-size`, dividindo-se por 2, e, em seguida, colocar a quantidade calculada de espaço acima e abaixo de cada linha de texto. Então, se você tem um `font-size` de 16px e um `line-height` de 24px, o `half-leading` perfeito seria de 4px. Aqui está o processo:

```
24px − 16px = 8px

8px ÷ 2 = 4px
```

O exemplo acima é uma visão ampla da sua fórmula.

[**Esse fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/GdAEf/) mostra a utilização da unidade `em`. A qual explico um pouco [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106962/quais-as-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-as-unidades-de-tamanhos-de-fonte-vw-em-e/107092#107092).

Mas, novamente, isso é tudo muito relativo, só espero que tenha ajudado. E concordo com o Gilherme Lopes, dê uma olhada nas exportações de css do Illustrator, pode realmente te ajudar.

[Fonte](http://joshnh.com/weblog/how-does-line-height-actually-work/)