# Font Responsiva

Tags: css, css-font-size

Estou fazendo um tema para wordpress e coloquei a font com o tamanho de `5em` o que fica em torno de `80px`, mas quando eu testo no meu celular com 320px de largura, a fonte fica quebrada e feia, eu queria algo que fizesse a fonte ficar automaticamente no tamanho necessário.

Meu css está assim atualmente:

```
#header .logo {
    height: 120px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A resposta do Samir está ótima, mas a medida `vm` não é suportada por alguns celulares mais antigos:

- Androids mais antigos que o 4.4 (como o 4.2 e 4.3)
- iOS7, IE11 e Edge só tem suporte parcial

<sub>(Fonte: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)</sub>

No caso provavelmente o seu layout também é responsivo, então você pode reaproveitar as suas media-queries existentes, por exemplo:

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
    elemento {
        font-size: [MEDIDA DESEJADA];
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1024px){
    elemento {
        font-size: [MEDIDA DESEJADA];
    }
}
```

Note que media-query não funciona em alguns browsers quando usado eles aninhados.

Se precisar de compatibilidade pro IE8 pode tentar este script que não tem dependencias com outros frameworks javascript: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Comment: Deixei o link pro canIUse na outra resposta, rsrs. Ótima resposta. ++

Comment: @SamirBraga upvote pra outra resposta, muito bem detalhada ;)

Answer (score 4):

Isso acontece porque o `em` vai pegar, no caso, uma porcentagem do tamanho da fonte do elemento pai, e não necessariamente o seu próprio tamanho (`height/width`), então se no mobile você não usar um *breakpoint* para definir um novo tamanho de fonte para o elemento pai a `div.logo` está certa em permanecer da mesma forma, já que sua referência não mudou.

Dessa forma, você pode usar o `vw` *unit* no elemento pai ou na própria `div`. Explico mais sobre essa unidade [**aqui**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106962/quais-as-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-as-unidades-de-tamanhos-de-fonte-vw-em-e/107092#107092).

Olhe esse exemplo([ou jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rs0tLs60/)):

> **Nota:** No StackSnippet clique em 
>   no botão <kbd>Página toda</kbd> e no jsfiddle modifique manualmente o tamanho da janela ou do iframe

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#header{
    font-size: 2vw;
}
#header .logo{
    height: 180px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <p>Font responsiva.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ou você pode criar os breakpoints que disse antes. Veja [esse exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/j1xebttd/). Repare que mudo apenas  fonte do `#header`.

Comment: Boa explicação, ótimo link da outra resposta +1

Comment: Eu não entendi o porque do downvote, mas suponho que seja por que o código estava em outro link ao invés do stacksnippet, então  removido margens da página pra evitar quebra do texto e adicionei o código no stacksnippet pra não depender de ferramentas de terceiros.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, obrigado pela edição :) . Também acho que foi por isso.