# Font reponsive com css

Tags: html5, css3

Boa tarde,
Estou fazendo uma página html e tem uns blocos que são responsivos. Agora preciso que o texto exibido dentro deles tambem seja. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você pode usar o font-size em "em" e setar diferentes tamanhos para diferentes resoluções

Comment: Você pode usar "em", "rem", "vh" ou "vw"

Comment: Depende do que você chama de "responsivo", essa palavra não quer dizer nada na prática (é apenas um apelido bobo usado por quem não é da área, comumente usado pelo "marketing" para vender sites). Mais fácil explicar exatamente o efeito/resultado desejado e a dificuldade em obter, assim poderá ter respostas técnicas.

Comment: Leitura complementar: [Por que é recomendado utilizar a unidade “em” ao invés de “px” para fontes?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14217/70)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Font Responsiva](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142676/font-responsiva)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma alternativa para que você tenha total controle do redimensionamento das suas fontes é utilizar as próprias media queries do `css`:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    p {font-size: 12px;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    p {font-size: 16px;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    p {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

Nesse caso você pode criar quantas regras achar necessário.

A segunda opção seria realmente utilizar `em`. Cada `em` corresponde ao tamanho atual da fonte, que por default nos browsers é `16px`. Ou seja:

```
p {
    font-size: 1em; //16px
}
h1 {
    font-size: 2em; //32px
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em; //24px;
}
```

Comment: Recomendo que antes de responder pesquise http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=texto%20responsivo

Answer (score 1):

No padrão EM, **1 EM normalmente equivale a 16 pixels**, ou seja, a medida que o browser considera como padrão para textos. Utilizar EM é uma questão de acessibilidade, pois pessoas com dificuldade de leitura podem aumentar e diminuir livremente o tamanho do texto de maneira proporcional. O que dá mais liberdade para o usuário, sem quebrar o seu layout!

Deixo aqui uma **opção** caso seja interessante para você. 
Veja que 16 pixels = 100%, 10 pixels é igual a 62.5%. (16 x 0.625 = 10).
Caso queira **torna bem mais fácil calcular** os valores a partir de uma base decimal. É possível definir o *body* com valor *font-size: 62.5%* como padrão para todo o documento. Assim **fazer com que 1em passa a ser equivalente a 10px**

Então ficaria assim:

```
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.bloco {
  width: 100%; 
}
.bloco p {
  font-size: 1em; /* Conforme explicado acima, seria equivalente a 10px */
}
```

Um texto de 12px, por exemplo, seria equivalente a 1.2em(Leia a explicação acima). Já um header com 36px seria equivalente a 3.6em(Leia a explicação acima).

Resolvi compartilhar esta solução que havia aplicado num projeto com necessidades relacionado à texto responsivo, aumentar e diminuir livremente o tamanho do texto de maneira proporcional.

Comment: Fera: `1em = 16px`, `1.6em = 25.6px`

Comment: Olá, sim!  Só para deixar 'redondo', redefinindo o font-size no body com font-size: 62.5%; 16 pixels = 100%, 10 pixels é igual a 62.5%. (16 x 0.625 = 10). Então é só definir este valor como padrão para todo o documento. Utilizando esta regrinha 1em passa a ser equivalente a 10px. Sacou?

Comment: Entendi, sugiro então que aninhe no mesmo bloco as regras, para que fique mais claro!

Comment: Obrigado! Já mudei.

Comment: Recomendo que antes de responder pesquise http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=texto%20responsivo

Comment: Ok! Aproveitando por estar logado, resolvi compartilhar uma solução diferente que havia aplicado num projeto com necessidades relacionado à texto responsivel

Comment: texto responsivo*

Comment: Pode compartilhar nas perguntas mais antigas que já possuem resposta e as que notar que são duplicatas basta sinalizar, assim evita de espalhar o conteudo.

Comment: Ok. tá certo! Vou ficar ligado.