# Font responsiva conforme tamanho do texto

Tags: css, html5

Como posso fazer uma fonte *responsiva* de acordo com o tamanho do texto?
Tenho um site: [radioturn.com.br](http://radioturn.com.br)

O nome da música se atualiza constantemente, gostaria de remover o marque e deixa-la parada, porém, algumas músicas são grandes demais e não cabem na div pai.

Como posso fazer isso?

Não quero usar text-overflow.

Comment: você esta a usar bootstrap ou esta fazendo tudo a mão ?

Comment: Estou fazendo a mão, com bootstrap é possível?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Font Responsiva](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142676/font-responsiva)

Comment: obs.: o site ta bem legal.

Comment: Já pensou em recortar o texto, incluir "..." no fim e adicionar o nome completo na propriedade title, normalmente é feito assim? Não creio que seja possível de uma forma simples ajustar o tamanho da fonte de acordo com o espaço disponível. Mas mesmo que seja possivel, não acho que vai ficar tão bom. Vai parecer que teu site não segue um padrão.

Comment: Vocês está falando de text-overflow: ellipsis? Preciso que o nome da música seja completo.

Comment: Você quer que o tamanho do texto diminua caso seu número de caracteres for largo? Ou fazer um recorte como dito por @mauhumor?

Comment: .player .caixa-status .som {
 font-family:Segoe UI Bold;
 font-size:40px;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 width:300px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

Comment: @PauloSérgioFilho Minha internet estava lenta, acho que sei do que está falando.

Comment: Você poderia tentar trocar o px da fonte, por em ou %. Mas isso só teria efeito se o tamanho da tela mudar. Acredito eu.

Comment: @PauloSérgioFilho acabei de deixar uma resposta, você pode analizar e adaptar no seu projecto !

Comment: O que você precisa é de algo tipo "overflow:resize-text;". Mas isso não existe. Talvez tenha que calcular no Javascript. Como já responderam(não testei).

Comment: Talvez isso aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358181/resize-font-size-according-to-div-size

Comment: Não me parece duplicata da indicada no fechamento. A indicada não resolve o que foi pedido, que é adequar o tamanho da fonte de acordo com o tamanho variável do texto, pra caber.

Comment: Usa o Font Awesome, é com Bootstrap, vai te economizar tempo e eles tem diversas funções.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Acho que você pode recriar o elemento que compõe o nome da música, e obter sua largura em pixels. Se sua largura é maior do que a largura de seu container, você pode resolver criar um `<marquee>`.

Para aplicar a recriação do elemento basta remover um dos `.som` existentes, e depois puxar o novo elemento ao mesmo container.

**Obs.:** A largura do span está sendo quebrada pelo próprio container, impedindo a comparação de sua largura com a de seu container. Algum estilo resolveria isso.

Lembrando que não é preciso re-criar o elemento marquee/span.

**Exemplo de como pré-armazenar o marquee/span:**

```
var span = document.createElement('span');

span.className = 'som';
/* Desaplica a largura fixa de 300px: */
span.width = 'auto';

var marquee = document.createElement('marquee');
marquee.className = 'som';
```

**Exemplo de como atualizar o nome da música:**

```
/* Remove o marquee por precaução: */
marquee.remove();

var nomeDaMúsica = 'Nome da música';

var container = document.querySelector(
    '.player .caixa-status'
);

span.textContent = nomeDaMúsica;

// Para obter a largura renderizada do span vai ser necessário
// adicioná-lo ao container (obs.: se ele já estiver adicionado
// ele não duplica, de acordo com meu navegador):
container.appendChild(span);

var largura = som.offsetWidth;

if (largura > container.offWidth) {
    /* Transforma o elemento span em marquee: */

    span.remove();

    marquee.textContent = nomeDaMúsica;
    container.appendChild(marquee);
}
```

Comment: Não entendi muito como fazer, ainda sou novo em javascript.

Comment: @PauloSérgioFilho Você teria que fazer isso à cada vez que você atualiza o nome da música atual. Já viu o edit, também (havia um typo)?

Comment: Está retornando o seguinte erro: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null at (index):39

Comment: ´@PauloSérgioFilho Você está fazendo isso antes do container ser declarado, como pode ser visto no elemento `<head>`. Tentou declarar o elemento `<script>` no fim de `<body>` ou espere a página carregar para executar o código? Pelos meus testes, depois da página carregar, o container estava sendo sucessivamente pego.

Comment: Testei, e criou um marquee junto com span.

Comment: @PauloSérgioFilho Ainda estou tentando achar o problema.

Comment: Ok, estou aguardando.

Answer (score 3):

Tentei analisar o seu caso usando o **javascript**. Você pode adapta-lo de acordo o seu projecto usando outra linguanges se possivel.

- Primeiro escolha um limite pra o tamanho dos titulos das musicas
- Recupere o tamanho do titulo da musica
- Se o tamanho exceder o limite, aplique uma fonte especifica
- Se nao, mantém a fonte padrao.

Pra testar o script basta mudar o **Titulo da  Musica** No codigo **HTML** ( o texto na baliza span )

```js
function Adapfont(limit){
  var titulo_da_musica = document.getElementById("t").innerText ;
  
  if(titulo_da_musica.length > limit){
     document.getElementById("t").style.fontSize = "large";
  }else{
     document.getElementById("t").style.fontSize = "xx-large";
  }
}
var limit = 20 ;
Adapfont(limit);
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="titulo-musica" id="t">Titulo da Musica</span>
</div>
```

**SUGESTAO** :

Uma outra solucao pra o seu caso seria limitar o numero de caracteres no titulo da musica.

Answer (score 3):

**Edição 1**

Bem, eu li erroneamente a pergunta e acabei respondendo sobre responsividade de acordo com a ***viewport***. Correndo o risco de ter votos negativos, deixarei minha resposta, **mesmo errada**, porque pode ser útil.

---

Você pode conseguir responsividade na tipografia usando somente CSS.

Primeiro, você pode recorrer à unidade ***[em](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.pt_BR.html)*** ou à ***%***:

```
body {
    /**
    Faz a fonte ficar 2 vezes maior que o normal
    **/
    font-size: 2em;
    /**
    Fonte 95% do tamanho do normal
    font-size: 95%;
    **/
}
```

Ou ainda, aliar esses tipos de fonte com ***[media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries)*** ou, ainda, usar as media queries com os tamanhos de fonte para cada tamanho de tela:

```
/**
    Tela com até 600px
**/
@media (max-width: 600px){
    body{
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}

/**
    Tela com até 959px, maior que 600px
**/
@media (max-width: 959px){
    body{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
/**
    Tela com 960px +
**/
@media (min-width: 960px){
    body{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

**A melhor solução CSS**

Use a unidade ***[vw](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)***

```
body{
    font-size: 8vw;  
}
```