# Como fazer textos responsivos?

Tags: css

Eu sei que para elementos normais, podemos usar a porcentagem, para que fiquem proporcionais às resoluções de tela. Mas e os textos? Qual a unidade de medida relativa, para que ele fique "maior ou menor" conforme à tela de exibição?

Comment: acho que, assim como uma boa parte, senão a grande maioria dos elementos, precisamos usar as media queries para controlar isso...

Comment: você pode usar os `em`, que, respeitam a resolução que o próprio usuário coloca em seu dispositivo

Comment: duas coisas importantes que aprendi com design responsivo, 1 - não trave o zoom do site, não o deixe sem escala. 2- você não pode definir o tamanho do texto para o usuário, existem pessoas com miopia, e também usuários que preferem as letras minúsculas, então deixe que seu usuário decida

Comment: Duplicata desta pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142676/3635, esta resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142695/3635 ou esta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142689/3635 resposta devem lhe ajudar.