# Como definir height em percentagem usando css

Tags: css

Existe algum forma de definir `height:80%` sendo 80% o valor do tamanho da div que ocupa no ecrã em css?

```
class="wrapper" style="height: 80%;">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para usar medidas em relação à área exibida, use `vw` e `vh`.

Veja que o exemplo em amarelo é relativo à àrea do quadro (*viewport width* e *viewport height*).

Clique em <kbd>página toda</kbd> logo no canto do *snippet* e compare.

Se usar porcentagem, o elemento é relativo à div superior, desde que o posicionamento dela e da superior não sejam fixo ou absoluto (a interna pode até pode ter posição absoluta). É o exemplo em vermelho, 80% da altura  da div amarela, e metade da largura.

```css
#d1 {
  background:yellow;
  width:50vw;
  height:80vh;
}

#d2 {
  background:red;
  height:80%;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1">
  <div id="d2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Para uma comparação entre várias unidades de medida do CSS, veja estes posts:

> [Por que é recomendado utilizar a unidade "em" ao invés de "px" para fontes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14217/70)

> [Quais as diferenças entre as unidades de tamanhos de fonte "vw", "em" e "%"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106962/70)