# Imagem em tela cheia usando o parallax do Materialize

Tags: jquery, css, html5, css3, materialize

Estou começando com o Materialize, e estou com uma dúvida.

Como deixar em tela cheia a imagem de fundo do `parallax`?

Atualmente, a imagem de funto fica na metade da tela.

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .parallax-container {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

**BUDDY**

```
<div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax"><img src="bg.png"></div>
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper teal darken-4">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">Logo</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.parallax').parallax();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Separe o seu código e coloque nesta ordem como esta nos modelos exemplos na **api** do **materialize**:

Exemplo [parallax](https://materializecss.com/templates/parallax-template/preview.html).

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper teal darken-4">
    <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">Logo</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="parallax-container">
  <div class="parallax">
    <img src="bg.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Cheque se sua imagem está no padrão dos modelos dele, 1440x743 mas isso não é regra, apenas precisa de uma imagem grande!

Se os styles na tag head e os scripts js estiverem no local correto tudo deve funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Para o seu caso em particular eu sugiro colocar a altura do container parallax com `100vh`, pois `VH` é relativo ao Viewport, ou seja nesse casso fica com 100% da altura.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        .parallax-container {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="parallax-container">
        <div class="parallax">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section white">
        <div class="row container">
            <h2 class="header">Parallax</h2>
            <p class="grey-text text-darken-3 lighten-3">Parallax is an effect where the background content or image in
                this case, is moved at a different speed than the foreground content while scrolling.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ex vero aspernatur in nobis, a dolor quo eaque
            corrupti dolorem, quas tenetur dignissimos, ipsa illo quis facere saepe voluptatibus vel id consequuntur
            optio laudantium fugit numquam suscipit. Neque, at accusamus, obcaecati quas, dolores quisquam maxime
            maiores dignissimos sunt molestiae error itaque debitis quasi perferendis sequi accusantium recusandae
            pariatur architecto unde! Sunt ipsam veniam libero mollitia, debitis at ipsum vel eum totam quae
            necessitatibus quas deleniti et exercitationem iusto alias saepe sapiente suscipit voluptatibus esse illum,
            asperiores consequatur, similique expedita? Eaque consectetur dolores est fuga repellat, inventore aliquid
            ex fugit quae corporis.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ex vero aspernatur in nobis, a dolor quo eaque
            corrupti dolorem, quas tenetur dignissimos, ipsa illo quis facere saepe voluptatibus vel id consequuntur
            optio laudantium fugit numquam suscipit. Neque, at accusamus, obcaecati quas, dolores quisquam maxime
            maiores dignissimos sunt molestiae error itaque debitis quasi perferendis sequi accusantium recusandae
            pariatur architecto unde! Sunt ipsam veniam libero mollitia, debitis at ipsum vel eum totam quae
            necessitatibus quas deleniti et exercitationem iusto alias saepe sapiente suscipit voluptatibus esse illum,
            asperiores consequatur, similique expedita? Eaque consectetur dolores est fuga repellat, inventore aliquid
            ex fugit quae corporis.</p>
    </div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.parallax').parallax();
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Para se informar mais sobre essa unidade de medida leia aqui [Quais as diferenças entre as unidades de tamanhos de fonte "vw", "em" e "%"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106962/quais-as-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-as-unidades-de-tamanhos-de-fonte-vw-em-e)