# Por que o Bootstrap 4 usa "rem" e "em" no lugar de pixels?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, scss

Como se pode ver [aqui](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss#L304) e [aqui](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss#L490), o Bootstrap 4 usa as unidades `rem` e `em` ao invés de usar em `px`.

Trecho do código usando a unidade `rem`:

```
$display1-size: 6rem !default;
$display2-size: 5.5rem !default;
$display3-size: 4.5rem !default;
$display4-size: 3.5rem !default;
```

Trecho do código usando `em`:

```
$input-height-inner: calc(#{$input-line-height * 1em} + #{$input-padding-y * 2}) !default;
```

Qual o motivo de não usarem pixels?

Comment: Talvez este artigo te ajude a entender: [Quando usar REM, EM, e Pixels](https://tableless.com.br/unidade-pixels-em-rem/)

Comment: Relacionada: [Por que é recomendado utilizar a unidade “em” ao invés de “px” para fontes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14217/5878)

Comment: Relacionada: [Quais as diferenças entre as unidades de tamanhos de fonte “vw”, “em” e “%”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106962/5878)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Basicamente é devida a acessibilidade e controle do layout do design system.

Usando medidas em `REM / EM` se o usuário mudar o tamanho da `font root` ele vai ter uma aumento homogêneo de todo o texto na tela. Na maioria dos browser o valor do font-size default é `16px`, equivalente a `1rem`. Então tendo todas a medidas relativas, se vc mudar o valor do `font root` vc muda toda a escala tipográfica da página. Porém mantendo a relação de hierarquia tipográfica definida. Assim como `margin` e `paddings` que tb são baseados em `rem/em`.

Vale ressaltar que `REM` e `EM` não são a mesma coisa, enquanto `REM` é relativo ao `font-size` do `:root`, o `EM` é relativo ao `font-size` declarado no elemento *(obviamente se vc não declarar nada ele pega como referência os 16px do root)*, por exemplo, se vc declara o elemento com `font-size` de `20px` e a `margin` com `0.5em`, esses `0.5` em correspondem a `10px`. Vc pode ler mais sobre isso aqui: [Por que é recomendado utilizar a unidade "em" ao invés de "px" para fontes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14217/por-que-%C3%A9-recomendado-utilizar-a-unidade-em-ao-inv%C3%A9s-de-px-para-fontes)

Então essa é uma forma de manter a consistência tipográfica do design system, se o usuário tiver problema de visão e configurar uma fonte maior para o browser, o Bootstrap vai se adaptar para não quebrar o layout e manter a "harmonia" do layout.

Veja um exemplo prático do que quero dizer. Essa é a hierarquia padrão dos `headers` do `user-agent`, repare que quando eu mudo o valor da font do root todos os `headers` mudam por igual. Essa é a intenção das fontes `rem/em`, fica mais fácil pro designer controlar o sistema, mesmo o usuário mudando o valor do `font root`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Teste vc mesmo para entender melhor :)

Mude o valor do font root para ver como tudo se adapta e vc continua com a hierarquia, vc muda o `font-size` em apenas um seletor `:root` e muda o tamanho de todos os textos do documento.

```css
:root {
 font-size: 16px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
h5 {
  font-size: 1em;
}
h6 {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Meu H1</h1><br>
<h2>Meu H2</h2><br> 
<h3>Meu H3</h3><br>
<h4>Meu H4</h4><br>
<h5>Meu H5</h5><br>
<h6>Meu H6</h6><br>
```

Veja um exemplo usando `@media` para aumentar o font root em telas grandes. Veja que se vc exibir o código em "tela cheia"  os `headers` tb vão aumentar. Apenas mudando o valor do `font-size` no `:root`, isso ajuda muito para vc customizar seu tema e uso do Bootstrap.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
:root {
 font-size: 16px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
h5 {
  font-size: 1em;
}
h6 {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 :root {
  font-size: 24px;
 }
}
```

```html
<h1>Meu H1</h1><br>
<h2>Meu H2</h2><br> 
<h3>Meu H3</h3><br>
<h4>Meu H4</h4><br>
<h5>Meu H5</h5><br>
<h6>Meu H6</h6><br>
```

---

### Bootstrap 5 + VW e o projeto RFS

Atualmente no Bootstrap **4.3** já é possível usar uma fonte mais responsiva, pois ela utiliza uma fórmula que usa a largura da tela para definir o tamanho da fonte do site. Na verdade ela deixa a fonte responsiva até **1200px** que é o maior `breakpoint` e a partir daí ela fixa o tamanho da fonte para ela não crescer mais.

Link do projeto RFS (responsive font size) https://github.com/twbs/rfs

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .title {
    font-size: calc(1.525rem + 3.3vw); /* repare na medida em vw */
  }
}
```

> **Our biggest new addition to Bootstrap in v4.3 is responsive font sizes**, a new project in the Bootstrap GitHub org to automate calculate an appropriate `font-size` **based on the dimensions of a visitor’s device or browser viewport**.

Traduzindo: *"Nossa maior nova adição ao Bootstrap na v4.3 são os tamanhos de fonte responsivos, um novo projeto na Bootstrap GitHub org para automatizar o cálculo de um tamanho de **fonte apropriada com base nas dimensões do dispositivo de um visitante ou do viewport do navegador**."*

Vc pode conferir no gráfico para entender melhor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Documentação oficial: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/typography/#responsive-typography

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]